# Huawei E3372H-320 AT Commands

Tags: linux, modem, huawei

I have a modem usb stick **Huawei E3372H-320** and I'm trying to get it work with **AT Commands**.

The problem is that I cannot see any `ttyUSB` inside `/dev`.

The modem is recognized `lsusb` gives me:

```
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 12d1:14db Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E353/E3131
```

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 (5.11.0-41-generic)

Any suggestions?

Comment: might need to load firmware via USB first. Every modem is different... maybe looking into "usb modeswitch" might help.

Comment: anyway, the part of dmesg that appears right after you plug in your modem would help, possibly.